# Document library Power app form - GET browser URL

Tags: powerapps-forms

I have created a Document library Power app form. That power app form will be opened on Edit of any item in document library. Is there any way to get the URL of the browser in Power App ? example
browser URL is

> https://....sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/TestList/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=90&customParam=ABC

Power app library form opens when above link is clicked.

I want to get the ID or customParam from the URL.
Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

the PowerApps, If you want to get the query string parameter value from the URL, you can use the `Param()` function as the following:

```
Param("ID")
```

In your formula, you can create a variable and set it with the query string value to can use it within your app as below

```
Set(VariabelName, Value(Param("ID")));
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using Param("ID") for label but It display nothing though the URL is https://....sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/TestList/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=90